# Space between vertical divs and alignment

Tags: html, css

I have some problems with div spacing.
Here is the html:

```
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-circle checkbox-business">
                    <input id="checkbox-business-id" class="styled" type="checkbox">
                    <label for="checkbox-business-id">BUSINESS</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-circle checkbox-health">
                    <input id="checkbox-health-id" class="styled" type="checkbox">
                    <label for="checkbox-health-id">HEALTH</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-circle checkbox-science">
                    <input id="checkbox-science-id" class="styled" type="checkbox">
                    <label for="checkbox-science-id">SCIENCE</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-circle checkbox-technology">
                    <input id="checkbox-technology-id" class="styled" type="checkbox">
                    <label for="checkbox-technology-id">TECHNOLOGY</label>
                </div>
            </div>
           </div>
```

and CSS:

```
.checkbox-business {
   margin-top: 10px;
 }

.checkbox-health {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.checkbox-science {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.checkbox-technology {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

[image]

I want to let some space between divs and I want all the checkboxes to be aligned.I am not able to do this. Also, I am using bootstrap.

Could someone take a look at it ?

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/paul28/do5efo1w/2/

Comment: Well first you need to find whatever's setting `text-align: center;` and remove it.

Comment: What are you using to style your checkboxes as they are looking like radio buttons to me?

Comment: Exactly, I want to be circle style.

Comment: text-align: center; seems to be defined in bootstrap classes.

Comment: they are properly aligned on my machine. Seems some style on the conatiner div is centering the checkboxes. Check what Niet suggested to check

Comment: my container class is from bootstrap, it's a lot of code there

Comment: which boostrap 3 or 4?

Comment: Can you please add a fiddle? I can't reproduce it. They are aligned when I try.

Comment: I am using bootstrap 3

Comment: Yes, I will add a fiddle in a few moments.

Comment: use custom css and markup mentioned in this link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

Comment: they are align properly here. Try clearing your browser history

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap, you should try to do things the "Bootstrap way". See the documentation for v3 here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#input-groups-checkboxes-radios

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/paul28/do5efo1w/2/
please read my comment from CSS line 658 @Orlandster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following styles. This should do what you want

```
header.masthead {
    text-align: left;
}
.checkbox {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 30px;
}

.checkbox label::before {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;

}
.checkbox label::after {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}


.checkbox input {
    width: 20px;
    height: 16px;
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after, .checkbox input[type="radio"]:checked + label::after {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f00c";
    font-size: 18px;
        padding: 1px 5px;
}
.checkbox label {
    padding-left: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

Check updated code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/do5efo1w/4/)

Comment: Thanks ! You have an idea to make the checkboxes much larger ?

Comment: Also, I need the checkbox and the label to be at the same level, can you help me?

Comment: Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

This Will help you

```
.checkbox {
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```